# Listing values for managed properties

Tags: 2010, web-services, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

I want to build an advanced search inside a web application. To do that, I connect to a Sharepoint 2010 instance running FAST and use the query web service.

I've tried to retrieve the search metadata to be able to build drop-downs with all possible values for e.g. the author property using the [`getSearchMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsearch.queryservice.getsearchmetadata%28v=office.14%29.aspx) call but I only get a listing of the properties, not all the values they can take.

```
<Properties diffgr:id="Properties5"
    msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
    <Name>Author</Name>
    <Description>author</Description>
    <Type>System.String</Type>
    <Retrievable>true</Retrievable>
    <FullTextQueriable>true</FullTextQueriable>
</Properties>
```

How can I query for all possible values of a managed property?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Refinements to find all the possible values for Managed Properties.  Refinements will also include the counts for each Managed Property.

Look here for more details on how to configure:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394639%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am actually using refinements, but don't they apply to the current query only? E.g. if I search for the text 'management', only the refinements applicable for documents matching that query will be returned.

Comment: That's correct, the refinements will only show for the current query.  Are you trying to find all the possible values of "management" before the user runs a query?

Comment: yes, I want to find out all the values before running a query.

Comment: If that's the case -> You're going to have to perform a search for "everything" and get your distinct list of "management" values from that.  You could even do a search for "everything" and use a refinement on the "management" managed property to get all the distinct values & counts.

Comment: I've tried to search for a single whitespace character. Do you have a better idea for searching for everything?

Comment: Use the "hashtag" or "pound sign" (whatever you call it) 

#